# Pause script execution on opera dragonfly

Tags: opera, pausing-execution, opera-dragonfly

In Chrome dev tools we can use  the 'Pause' icon on the bottom row of the interface  to break on all exceptions. So when our web page is running, we can break it suddenly without adding breakpoint and know where the script stop.
Can we do that in opera dragonfly?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a "Show parse errors and break on exceptions" toggle (immediately left of the drop-down selecting what script to show currently).

Comment: Break on error
It is possible to get Opera Dragonfly to stop execution when a parse error occurs. Enabling the last button in the Scripts toolbar will stop JavaScript execution at the line where the parse error occurred and highlight it in the gutter in a similar manner to breakpoints. The same button will also stop execution when an exception is thrown.

I can break it even no perse error occur? Thanks.