# Break point on opera Dragonfly

Tags: opera, breakpoints, opera-dragonfly

In opera dragonfly, we have 2 button:

1. **Break on first statement of a new script**
   pauses the execution each time a new script is loaded and the first statement is evaluated.
2. **Break on error**, but in dragonfly it's called "Show parse errors and break on exceptions"
   Description: 
   It is possible to get Opera Dragonfly to stop execution when a parse error occurs. Enabling the last button in the Scripts toolbar will stop JavaScript execution at the line where the parse error occurred and highlight it in the gutter in a similar manner to breakpoints. The same button will also stop execution when an exception is thrown.

What is it the second break "Show parse errors and break on exceptions" ? 
When I load gmail page it will stop execution. It's the same like pause on all exceptions?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

yes. Break on error simply pauses execution when exception is thrown or script cannot be parsed, this is quite handy.

but an anyway, you kinda already answered your own question.

Comment: simply pauses execution when exception is thrown or script cannot be parsed. But when there is no error at all, can I paused it and know where the script execution is halted? Thanks.

Comment: **nope**. You can only pause on events, breakpoints, errors, and on start of new file.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11467833/pause-script-execution-on-opera-dragonfly/11488083#11488083
So this is not true?

Comment: why ? - its true - because exceptions ARE errors, in general sense.